# How can I make mypy work with a custom class decorator similar to dataclass?

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-dataclasses

I need to generate code for classes in a very similar way `dataclasses.dataclass` does. In my first version, I wrote something like:

```py
def typedrow(cls: type[_T]) -> type[_T]:
    cls_annotations = cls.__dict__.get("__annotations__", {})

    def __init__(s, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        for field_name in cls_annotations.keys():
            s.__dict__[field_name] = kwargs.get(field_name)

    setattr(cls, "__init__", __init__)
    return cls
```

Although my code works, `mypy` is quite unhappy when I write:

```py
@typedrow
class Person:
    name: Optional[str] = None

p = Person(name="joe")
```

It complains with `error: Unexpected keyword argument "name" for "Person"`.

I noticed that `dataclasses.dataclass` does something completely different. Instead, it generates the code in text and calls `_create_fn`. Given that the generated code has all the type hints, it is kind obvious why `mypy` gets happy.

How does that work *exactly*?

I tried to create a simplified version of `_create_fn` which seems to be generated exactly the same code as `dataclass`, however, `mypy` is still unhappy.

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html: *"Mypy does not yet recognize aliases of `dataclasses.dataclass`, and will probably never recognize dynamically computed decorators."* - My guess is that mypy has hard coded special treatment of `dataclass`.

Comment: I see that the implementation for dataclasses in mypy is here: https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py. Apparently there are "plugins" in mypy and maybe the solution is to write your own plugin: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#extending-mypy-using-plugins

Comment: Another idea: instead of doing something *similar* to `dataclass`, can you just *use* `dataclass`?

Comment: I'm working with `pyspark` which defines `pyspark.sql.types.Row`. I actually started using dataclass but conversion between `Row` and my dataclasses is now a bottleneck. I'm now using `Row.asDict()` to update a class `self.__dict__` directly. Not sure this is a good approach. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mypy recognises the function `dataclasses.dataclass` by tracking how you import the name, then [implementing custom type checking logic on the decorated class](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/bcd4ff231554102a6698615882074e440ebfc3c9/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py#L202). This is all done in the mypy linting session, and has nothing to do with your Python runtime, so looking through the `dataclasses.dataclass` implementation is the wrong start.

[PEP 681 - Data Class Transforms](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/#the-dataclass-transform-decorator) is dedicated for your use case. The following can be checked on [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f549489f503d936686fcddb05c7a7091):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing_extensions as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    _T = t.TypeVar("_T")

@t.dataclass_transform(eq_default=False, kw_only_default=True)
def typedrow(cls: type[_T], /) -> type[_T]:
    cls_annotations = cls.__dict__.get("__annotations__", {})

    def __init__(s: _T, *args: t.Any, **kwargs: t.Any) -> None:
        for field_name in cls_annotations.keys():
            s.__dict__[field_name] = kwargs.get(field_name)

    setattr(cls, "__init__", __init__)
    return cls
```

```
>>> @typedrow
... class Person:
...     name: str | None = None
...
>>> p = Person(name="joe")  # OK
>>> p = Person("joe")  # mypy: Too many positional arguments for "Person"  [misc]
>>> p = Person(name=1)  # mypy: Argument "name" to "Person" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str | None"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Why do we need `from __future__ import annotations` and `if TYPE_CHECKING`?

Comment: @IgorGatis it’s not needed here, but it’s an indicator that the symbols are intended for static typing only, not runtime introspection. Remove them if you want.